# Filtering Drug Adverse Events to Focus on Combination Products

Tags: openfda

The openFDA drug adverse event API returns data that has been collected from the FDA Adverse Event Reporting System (FAERS).  The FAERS data in the DTD Descriptor contains a field that identifies whether the product at issue is a combination product. https://www.fda.gov/combination-products/guidance-regulatory-information/reporting-elements-combination-products.  It should be "combinationproductreport". But I cannot find that field in the downloaded dataset.  Can anyone tell me where it is? I searched in the searchable fields and did not find it. Is there any workaround if it is not there?

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [FDA Adverse Event Reporting System (FAERS) Quarterly Data Extract Files](https://fis.fda.gov/extensions/FPD-QDE-FAERS/FPD-QDE-FAERS.html), which openFDA uses as a *source* for its Drug AE API, do not contain any information about safety reports for CDER and CBER-regulated combination products, and the openFDA team is unaware of a workaround. You would need to contact the FDA directly to see if this is going to change in the future. Sorry about the inconvenience.